# Foreach Loop Only Displaying One Value From Array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I have tried researching other questions similar to my problem, but I haven't found anything that addresses this specifically. I am selecting data using mysqli and displaying it in a table. The column `table_yard` can have multiple values, so I exploded those values and stored them as an array to be looped through and then stored the result in variable `$yard_name`. I later assign this variable to a row in my table like so (`$get` is storing the sql query):

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $yards = explode(",", $row[table_yard]);
foreach ($yards as $yard) {
    $yard_name = $yard . ", ";
}
    $table_rows .= "<tr>
                <td>" . mdy($row[table_date]) . "</td>
                <td>" . $yard_name . "</td>
                </tr>";
```

The problem is, if there is more than one value in that array, it only displays the first item. I ran a debug on `$yards` to see if it was even getting all the values of the array, and it is, as shown here:

```
Array (
[0] => 711
[1] => 2793
[2] => 988
)
```

Although, this is what gets displayed in the `<td>` cell:

```
711,
```

What I want it to display is this:

```
711, 2793, 988
```

I am sure it's a rookie mistake, but I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You're overwriting the `$yard_name` variable with every loop of the foreach

Comment: why do you don't use `$yard_name =  implode(", ", explode(",", $row[table_yard]));`

Comment: $yard_name .= $yard . ", ";

Comment: But its showing 711, or 988,?

Comment: @Bankzilla Aha! I knew it was something simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Eugen I had actually thought about using that method instead, although I may still use it in another section of my code. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @ShaifulIslam It was showing 711, but it is working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested but this should help fix the issue. Defining `$yard_name` before the loop so it doesn't get constantly overwritten

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get)) {
    $yards = explode(",", $row[table_yard]);
    $yard_name = "";
    foreach ($yards as $yard) {
        $yard_name .= $yard . ", "; // Add to the string instead of overwriting
    }
    $table_rows .= "<tr>
        <td>" . mdy($row[table_date]) . "</td>
        <td>" . trim($yard_name, ",") . "</td>
    </tr>";
}
```